# Content Management System - PHP - Asp.Net

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, dotnetnuke, umbraco

I am new to open source Content Management System tools. I got a website using Joomla for content management. Now, I am just thinking to Umbraco or Dotnetnuke (any Asp.net based) frameworks to use. Will it be a complex to do this migration. Can you suggest pros and cons for this idea.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: More details are needed in order to adequately answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Umbraco ...

Most of your client-side code like HTML, CSS and JavaScript can just be copied straight over, but as expected it may require some fiddling.

As for the data, it might be worth looking into the [CMSImport](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cmsimport) module for Umbraco. As long as you can convert the source data into one of the formats recognised by the module, you should be able to upload your content with ease. I've had no personal experience with this module, but should be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the size of the site and the functionality requirements. For smaller sites, it may be as easy as implementing the skin based on the original design (or, if a custom design isn't needed, selecting a free or 3rd party skin) and then manually migrating the content. For really large sites, you should be able to write scripts to migrate the content. I'm not aware of any products that do this. You'll also probably need to select some modules to use for things like forms.